# Having difficultly in figuring out the working of split function in java

Tags: java, split, spaces

The String i want to split is " He is a very very good boy, isn't he? ".
When i used only the split function the out put also printed the space after "boy," in the string. To remove that i put an if condition in the code and then the code doesn't print anything after boy .

Can someone tell me why this is happening ? Also if there is a better way to solve this problem other than using Guava .

```
public class Solution {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      String s=scan.nextLine();

      String []tokens = s.trim().split("[\\s,'?]");
      int n = tokens.length;
        System.out.println(n);
      for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++)
      {
          if(tokens[i].charAt(0)==' ')
          {
             continue;
          }

          System.out.println(tokens[i]);
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to be the output?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: A bit odd to be splitting on the `'`, isn't it?

Comment: We really need to know the "rules" when to split the words, otherwise we won't be able to help you

Comment: no wonder you don't see anything else, you skip the loop with continue. Try removing the space instead (e.g. with using a StringBuilder or printing every char except the first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling `split` to split on a *single* character from that list. If you want it to split on one *or more* (e.g., runs of those characters), add `+` after it to say "one *or more* of the thing before":

```
String []tokens = s.trim().split("[\\s,'?]+");
// Here ----------------------------------^
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/B29FBK)

(FWIW, including `'` on the list of characters to split on seems a bit odd, but we don't know your use case, so...)

Comment: Thanks ,it worked . Can you please also tell me why the for loop end in this code as soon as it printed boy. That's the part that confused me  the most. I used ' to split as this is was stated in the problem i was trying to solve

Comment: @AmanKumarSinha: It wouldn't have *ended*, it would have crashed with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. With your original regex, the entry after `"boy"` is `""` (see [this version](http://ideone.com/Oic11e) with your original regex), so `.charAt(0)` is asking for a character that doesn't exist, and fails.

Comment: Thanks . I will try ans read more about split function. I thought i also took space as a token there .

Comment: @AmanKumarSinha: No, spaces are on your delimiter list. What happened was you had two delimiters in a row (`,` and space), so you ended up with the "entry" between then (`""`). By adding `+`, you tell `split` to split on one *or more* delimiters, so we don't end up with the `""` entry.

Answer (score 0):

check this solution.

```
  String str="He is a very very good boy, isn't he?";
       String[] Val = str.split("[' ,@!_.?]+");
       System.out.println(Val.length);
       for(String token :Val) {
              System.out.println(token);}}
```